# Apache Wicket BackButton support Browser Compatibility issue

Tags: java, browser, wicket

I am a newbie evaluating wicket framework for development and I have encountered a problem while trying to implement the Browser BackButton support feature of wicket.

After reading the documentation and forum discussions on the same topic I tried to put my components and everything in a form and used the -

```
         form.setVersioned(true);
```

for enabling the Browser BackButton Support.

This works fine for Mozilla Firefox. However, the Back Button of Chrome and Internet Explorer fails to deliver the same functionality. This issue has created concern in my further exploration of wicket. Please help.

Comment: What problems are you seeing in Chrome and IE?

Comment: Thanks for reply. My specific problem with various browsers is as follows: 
My app has a table and on click of a button i add a row to that table.Pressing browser back button after adding row in - 
 1. Firefox : Takes me to state when no row was added to table. 
 2. Chrome and Internet Explorer : The whole URL before the current app was run in browser.

Answer (score 1):

probably it is not about serVersioned(true) that is in most cases true by default. The most important thing is to call modelChanging() and modelChanged() methods to notify Wikcet about changes.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/browser-back-forward.html

Comment: link has broken . could you please update the link please . I really want to sorted out some issue

Comment: I'd guess this is the site: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27670